# Linq to SQL in web app -vs- web site?

Tags: linq, .net-4.0

When creating a LINQ to SQL class (dbml) in an App_Code folder for a web app (-vs- web site) why can't I access the DataContext the same way as I do in a web site?

What is the right way to access the class?

TIA
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it had to do with the different ways that web apps and web sites handle the App_Code folder. If the same Linq To SQL class is created in the root of the web site -vs- the App_Code folder it works fine.

So the issue is not Linq but rather namespaces.

J

Comment: Yes, this caught me the first few times I messed around with Web Apps in VS as opposed to Web Sites. If you add a class file to a sub folder of the main project root, it appends the namespace with the folder name. However, you can just remove the prefix from the namespace and then you don't have to move your file to the root folder.